# What is a tick sign in front of .xml file in android studio

Tags: android-studio

What is the tick symbol and how to remove it ?

Did I accidentally set something ?

[image: as described in the question]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you pressed F11 or Ctr+F11. It is a simple book mark, like those in other browsers, used for later view, usage, etc.
Check this for other shortcuts [link](https://medium.com/@gotoark/most-useful-shortcut-keys-for-android-studio-with-bonus-plugins-bf95c85427f0).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bookmark feature in Android Studio. Useful, When you are working on most frequent files. Try pressing `F3` to remove the bookmark or creating the bookmark. If `F3`, `F11` or `Ctrl+F11` is not working for you, go to the `Android Studio Preference Settings -> Keymap` and now search for the "bookmark". You will find the `Toggle Bookmark` option there and so is your respective hot key.