# Android Studio - tick next to class name

Tags: android-studio

I accidently pressed a key and now I have a tick mark next to one of my files (see image). What is this, will it affect my project and how can I remove it?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might have accidentally pressed F11 or Ctrl+F11 to bookmark! Good feature for files you use quite often.
Check this for other shortcuts [link](http://pnsurez.blogspot.ro/2015/08/useful-android-studio-shortcut-in-day.html).

[Credit for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593449/what-is-a-tick-sign-in-front-of-xml-file-in-android-studio)